# Visual Basic: Creating a .png image

Tags: vb.net, image-processing

I want to create a Windows application with Visual Basic.
The application is pretty simple: It lets you choose 2 images, and when you click "Create" the application will create a new .png image from combining the two images' bitmaps. This new file will be created on a specified directory.

How do I do that?

Comment: How would it combine the images?

Comment: Combining images: Put one bitmap over another, then create a new .png image from the result.
@RedDeckWins: Smell what you wish, I care little. I don't expect you to understand my curiosity.

Comment: Well - you have to specify a way to blend the images. You could XOR the bits, or OR them, or or something else. If you just put one image on top of another, the result is the last image you've written. They're not combined at all.  Check out Paint.NET for the options on combining layers, to get a feel for the options here.

Comment: I know that putting two images over each other won't combine them. I need a way to "copy" the bitmaps of one image onto another, and then create a .png image from this result, which will be saved on the Desktop or something.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by combine?  Add the rgbs together?  put one on top of the other?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into LaVolpe's [32bpp DIB Suite](http://www.visualbasiccode.net/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=67466&lngWId=1). It provides a plethora of image management routines written in VB, including saving to the PNG format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you need just one picturebox , Just load an image on it using openfile file dialog and choose image , and then choose a combobox or sth like that to choose the type of the image , I hope this can help you :

```
Private Function GetImageFormatForSelectedCombo() As ImageFormat 
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem 
        Case "JPEG" 
            Return ImageFormat.Jpeg 
        Case "PNG" 
            Return ImageFormat.Png 
        Case "GIF" 
            Return ImageFormat.Gif 
        Case Else 
            Return ImageFormat.Jpeg 
    End Select 

End Function
```

Oh and , if you want us to collaborate with each other
to create a new program , that would be very nice ;) GOOD LUCK ;)